# jQuery stopImmediatePropagation() issue with mouseenter and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive

I've created a menu that is supposed to respond to hover (`mouseenter`/`mouseleave`) and `click` events so it will work with a mouse and touchscreen.

Here is a very simplified version:

```js
$('.menu-item')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
  .on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
  .on('blur mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.menu-item {background:red; text-align:center; padding:20px 0;}
.active {background:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-item">test</div>
```

The problem I'm having is touchpad triggers both `mouseenter` and `click` events when the element is touched, which causes the `'active'` class to be added, and then toggled off.  I have added the `stopImmediatePropagation()`, but both handlers are still triggered by the same event.

Comment: you'll have to check if it is a touch device, and remove `mouseenter event`